# scipy.optimize.newton, Como declarar la derivada?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

De la `libreria Scipy` para usar el `metodo de Newton` tengo que declarar las funciones y los parametros`scipy.optimize.newton(func, x0, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=50, fprime2=None)` El problema es que cuando declaro en el campo de `fprime` como mi derivada `p` el codigo no corre. Creo que el problema esta en como se estan declarando los argumentos, pero no logro dar con el error Coloco el codigo:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import integrate

n=763.0; s=762.0; b=0.0026; y=0.5673
def p(x,b,n,y,s): return 1.0/(x*(b*n+y*np.log(x)-s*b*x))
def Ui(x,x1,b,n,y,s): return (integrate.fixed_quad(p, x, x1, args=(b,n,y,s),    n=5)[0]-1.0)
```

De `optimize.newton` llamo en el tercer campo a la derivada que es mi funcion `p` y el codigo no corre.

> ```
> def t(x,x1,b,n,y,s): return optimize.newton(Ui, x1, p, args=(x,b,n,y,s),  maxiter=500)
> ```

```
x=0.99;  x1=1.0
X=[1]                
for _ in xrange(1,15): x1=round(t(x1,x, b, n, y, s),500); x=x1; X.append(x)
Xu = X[1:]
```

Si no declaro `p` el metodo usado es secante, y ahi el codigo si corre, pero me es necesario para tener una mejor aproximacion declarar la derivada.

[**Metodo de Newton en Scipy**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los argumentos que pasas en la tupla `args` del método `optimize.newton` son usados tanto para la función como para su derivada. El problema es que tu función tiene un parámetro más (`x1`) que su derivada. Esto te dará un error algo así:

> TypeError: p() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)

La solución simple sería pasarle ese parámetro a la derivada `p` aunque no se use para nada en la propia función:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import integrate

n=763.0; s=762.0; b=0.0026; y=0.5673
def p(x,x1,b,n,y,s):
    return 1.0/(x*(b*n+y*np.log(x)-s*b*x))
def Ui(x,x1,b,n,y,s): return (integrate.fixed_quad(p, x, x1, args=(x1,b,n,y,s),    n=5)[0]-1.0)
def t(x,x1,b,n,y,s): return optimize.newton(Ui, x1, p, args=(x1,b,n,y,s,),  maxiter=500)

x=0.99;  x1=1.0
X=[1]                
for _ in xrange(1,15):
    x1=round(t(x1,x, b, n, y, s),500)
    x=x1
    X.append(x)
    Xu = X[1:]
```